Swapped from Cake to Catamoto on Pancakeswap and lost my tokens
Here is the transaction..  I lost Anyone know how I can get them back/
From:
0x2440B5b7cF4619FD98cd43CeCa9039E3d9E6b0c5
Interacted With (To):
0x13f4EA83D0bd40E75C8222255bc855a974568Dd4 (PancakeSwap: Smart Router V3)
BEP-20 Tokens Transferred: 6
All Transfers
Net Transfers
From
0xAfB2Da14...bd7886c56
To
PancakeSwap: Smart Router V3
For
0.194466805304147605
$108.82
Wrapped BNB
(WBNB)
From
0x2440B5b7...3d9E6b0c5
To
0xAfB2Da14...bd7886c56
For
39.227330414028749685
$108.63
PancakeSwap ...
(Cake)
From
PancakeSwap: Smart Router V3
To
PancakeSwap V2: CATA 38
For
0.194466805304147605
$108.82
Wrapped BNB
(WBNB)
From
PancakeSwap V2: CATA 38
To
0x40594aD3...F6Fef3D00
For
509.476921498887840499
CATAMOTO
(CATA)
From
PancakeSwap V2: CATA 38
To
0x4Cc80D57...138d01A2F
For
509.476921498887840499
CATAMOTO
(CATA)
From
PancakeSwap V2: CATA 38
To
0x2440B5b7...3d9E6b0c5
For
100,876.430456779792418898
CATAMOTO
(CATA)

Hi, why do you think you lost the tokens, it shows your balance as 100,876.430456779792418898 CATA if calling balanceOf at the token contract. Is it just in the wallet UI that you don't see them? Try adding the address to your wallet UI as outlined here: https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360015489031-How-to-display-tokens-in-MetaMask#h_01FWH492CHY60HWPC28RW0872H | Additionally, a dollar value not displaying on a block explorer doesn't indicate the dollar value of that token. | Please also note that none of this means it is or isn't a scam.

You bought some token 'CATAMOTO'.
Try to sell it on pancake swap.
As I see CATAMOTO is worth nothin, if there is some liqudity you can get some or all money back. But you got scammed.
